# Issue with building Flutter project: 'Contents.json' source ref not found for Tflite target

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, xcode, terminal

Im having a problem running a flutterflow project that i downloaded into flutter
whenever i build i get this issue

`[!] Unable to find other source ref for` Contents.json`for target`tflite`.`

how do i solve it? i've tried removing the podfile, running again, cleaning, everything but nothing seems to work.

I've tried removing the podfile, running again, cleaning, everything but nothing seems to work.
I've been at it for hours now, pod install, removing pods, flutter clean, tflite everything im not sure what to do next.

this is the full error from terminal

```
Error output from CocoaPods:
↳
         Cloning into '/var/folders/x2/zlgs96496vn3th8n3wdmfzkr0000gn/T/d20230529-26360-vrerw8'...
         Note: switching to 'dce2e1abc6c0d5e830ff1cffe3f8633fda64001e'.

         You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
         changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
         state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.

         If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
         do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:

           git switch -c <new-branch-name>

         Or undo this operation with:

           git switch -

         Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false

         Cloning into '/var/folders/x2/zlgs96496vn3th8n3wdmfzkr0000gn/T/d20230529-26360-135yi23'...
         Note: switching to 'dce2e1abc6c0d5e830ff1cffe3f8633fda64001e'.

         You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
         changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
         state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.

         If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
         do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:

           git switch -c <new-branch-name>

         Or undo this operation with:

           git switch -

         Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false

         Cloning into '/var/folders/x2/zlgs96496vn3th8n3wdmfzkr0000gn/T/d20230529-26360-1m30fk5'...
         Note: switching to 'dce2e1abc6c0d5e830ff1cffe3f8633fda64001e'.

         You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
         changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
         state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.

         If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
         do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:

           git switch -c <new-branch-name>

         Or undo this operation with:

           git switch -

         Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false

         Cloning into '/var/folders/x2/zlgs96496vn3th8n3wdmfzkr0000gn/T/d20230529-26360-3yskua'...
         Note: switching to 'dce2e1abc6c0d5e830ff1cffe3f8633fda64001e'.

         You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
         changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
         state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.

         If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
         do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:

           git switch -c <new-branch-name>

         Or undo this operation with:

           git switch -

         Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false

         Cloning into '/var/folders/x2/zlgs96496vn3th8n3wdmfzkr0000gn/T/d20230529-26360-12jbr3f'...
         Note: switching to 'dce2e1abc6c0d5e830ff1cffe3f8633fda64001e'.

         You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
         changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
         state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.

         If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
         do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:

           git switch -c <new-branch-name>

         Or undo this operation with:

           git switch -

         Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false


Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro.


enter code here
```